# On duplicate key update for multiple values that aren't the primary key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to basically do an "insert if not exists else update" type query, and the way everything I've read tells me to go is [Insert into...On Duplicate Key Update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). The thing is, my primary key is an autoincrement value that I never interact with or keep track of and I can't really dynamically generate it to put into my query.

A typical row would be:

`ID| Project_ID | Location | Cost_Center_Category | Name | Number | Year | Q_1 |`

`1 | 200        |    NUH   | 1                    |asfoi | 1098123|etc.`

Basically the uniqueness (not literally) of each row came with the combination of Project_ID, Location, Cost_Center_Category, Name, Number, and year. If those all were identical, then an update to `Q_1` would occur.

```
UPDATE Labour_Planning 
        SET $Q = $submit
        WHERE Project_ID = $selected_project 
        AND Year = $selected_year 
        AND Cost_Center_Category = $CCC 
        AND Cost_Center_Name = '$CC' 
        AND Cost_Center_Number = '$CC_Number'
        AND Location = '$location';
```

Yeah, I know, SQL injection and all that, I will make this better. For now, I need to figure out a way to basically insert a row if ANY of the above columns are different. Is that possible with the Insert into....On Duplicate key?

Every example I see uses the primary key in their insert statement, and that's not really possible in this case.

Comment: Yes it's doable with a unique key, but seems to me like you'd be better off restructuring into 2 tables

Comment: `on duplicate` will trigger on ANY "unique key" violation.it's not just for primary keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to do this for fear of obnoxious overhead, but considering I won't actually have many updates/inserts at a time, I just went with this.

```
    $labour_select = "SELECT Project_ID 
                    FROM Labour_Planning 
                    WHERE Project_ID = $selected_project
                    AND Year = $selected_year 
                    AND Cost_Center_Category = $CCC 
                    AND Cost_Center_Name = '$CC' 
                    AND Cost_Center_Number = '$CC_Number'
                    AND Location = '$location';";
    $result = $mysqli->query($labour_select);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($num_rows == 0){
        $labour_insert = "INSERT INTO Labour_Planning (Project_ID, Location, Cost_Center_Category, Cost_Center_Name, Cost_Center_Number, Year, $Q) VALUES ($selected_project, '$location', $CCC, '$CC', '$CC_Number', $selected_year, $submit)";
        $insert_result = $mysqli->query($labour_insert);
    }
    else {
        $labour_update = "UPDATE Labour_Planning 
        SET $Q = $submit
        WHERE Project_ID = $selected_project 
        AND Year = $selected_year 
        AND Cost_Center_Category = $CCC 
        AND Cost_Center_Name = '$CC' 
        AND Cost_Center_Number = '$CC_Number'
        AND Location = '$location';";
        $update_result = $mysqli->query($labour_update);
    }
```

Now to look up prepared statements! I hear not only do they keep you protected from sql injection, it will make things of this nature faster as well! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have done some test and thats what I get

```
create table test.a (
  a int PRIMARY KEY,
  b int,
  c int
);

create UNIQUE index some_index on test.a(b,c);

insert into test.a VALUES (1,2,3); 
insert into test.a VALUES (2,2,3); -- fails
insert into test.a VALUES (2,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = 2; -- updates
```

Thus, all you need is to create composite unique index on fields that you consider must be unique.